# How to input this adjacency graph to list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, input

I have a data file with entries that look like this:

```
6->26:32
10->39:30
26->28:24
3->16:19
10->35:35
10->37:19
10->31:36
10->33:32
```

This is how I was trying to read them into a list, but it doesn't work for double-digit numbers.

```
import sys, re

data = []
for line in sys.stdin.readlines():
    data.append(line.strip())

for i in range(len(data)):
    cleandata = re.findall(r"[\w']", data[i])
    print(cleandata)
```

The output I get is this:

```
['6', '2', '6', '3', '2']
['1', '0', '3', '9', '3', '0']
['2', '6', '2', '8', '2', '4']
['3', '1', '6', '1', '9']
['1', '0', '3', '5', '3', '5']
['1', '0', '3', '7', '1', '9']
['1', '0', '3', '1', '3', '6']
['1', '0', '3', '3', '3', '2']
```

What I want is:

```
[6, 26, 32]
[10, 39, 30]
[26, 28, 24]...etc
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following regex instead:

```
cleandata = re.findall(r"\d+", data[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic approach using [`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20replace#str.replace):

```
with open('data.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        line = line.replace('->', ' ').replace(':', ' ')
        print(list(map(int, line.split())))
```

Which Outputs:

```
[6, 26, 32]
[10, 39, 30]
[26, 28, 24]
[3, 16, 19]
[10, 35, 35]
[10, 37, 19]
[10, 31, 36]
[10, 33, 32]
```

You can also use [`re.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split):

```
from re import split

with open('data.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        print(list(map(int, split('->|:', line.strip()))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to @blhsing's answer, you can use `[0-9]` too:

```
cleandata = re.findall(r"[0-9]", data[i])
```

If care about them as strings:

```
print(list(map(int,cleandata)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the variable data that you get is a list of string:

```
data = ["6->26:32","10->39:30","26->28:24","3->16:19","10->35:35","10->37:19","10->31:36","10->33:32"]
```

If all entries are positive integers, this code may help:

```
for line in data:
    entries =re.split("[^0-9]+",line)
    print(entries)
```

[^0-9]+ is regex pattern that matches all non-digit characters. Using re.split helps us remove "->" and ":". The output that I get is:

```
['6', '26', '32']
['10', '39', '30']
... etc
```